# Fractal laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть api которое возвращает список новостей и одну новость, нужно когда мы переходим на одну новость выводить еще одно поле.
Вот контролер.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Models\News;
use App\Transformers\NewsTransformer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $news = News::all();
        return fractal()
            ->collection($news)
            ->transformWith(new NewsTransformer)
            ->toArray();
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $news = News::findOrFail($id);
        return fractal()
            ->item($news)
            ->transformWith(new NewsTransformer)
            ->toArray();
    }
}
```

А вот Transformer.

```
<?php

namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Models\News;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class NewsTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
     public function transform(News $news)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $news->id,
            'title' => $news->title,
            'poster' => method_exists($news->pic, 'getImagePath') ? env('APP_URL') . '/' . $news->pic->getImagePath(true, "") : null,
            'url' => route('news.show', ['slug' => $news->slug, 'id' => $news->id]),
            'preview' => $news->preview,
            'category' => $news->category,
            'created_at' => Carbon::parse($news->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
    }

}
```

Как заинклудить ful_text когда я перехожу на новость, что бы не писать дополнительный transformer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще вот - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

Есть ресурсы. Есть коллекции.

Когда вы возвращаете список новостей, то вы должны использовать коллекцию

```
php artisan make:resource ExampleCollection

... 

<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ExampleCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
            'links' => [
                'self' => 'link-value',
            ],
        ];
    }
}

... В контроллере

return new UserCollection(News::all());
```

Когда же вы возвращаете одну новость, то это уже ресурс

```
php artisan make:resource ExampleResource

...

<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ExampleResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}

... Контроллер

return new ExampleResource(News::find(1));
```

Также обратите внимание на другие возможности - *Conditional Attributes* и *Conditional Relationships* (в том же топике по ссылке)